# How to compare and join similar columns in the same table in access report

Tags: ms-access-2016

[Table in Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g08F7.png)

I have created an access table that stores information on exports. Some of the columns store information on species of fish, labelled as Species 1, up to species 6 and their respective quantities as "Net Wt 1" up to "Net Wt 6".

My question is; I want to generate a report that will group the companies, Destination and then join data from Species 1 to Species 6 into one column called Species.

I have done a lot of search but not getting enough information

Something like this

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaICQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)! E.g. replace images with text data [formatted as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and add sample data and query code. Your issue is caused by poor database design, but can be resolved with improved db design (read on "Database normalization").

Comment: You need an extra table for the species on export with fields for`exportID`, `speciesID`and`quantity`, then just summing all quantities is easy and your actual data structure can be created with a [crosstab query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). This also enables having up to unlimited different species on an export (not limited to 6).